# Get Friends List in facebook Graph Api?

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

yesterday i got answer get friends list from facebook using App_id and App_secret  i got friends list.today  i trying to run the code i getting error.but same code working yesterday ?

today I am getting Error Like this

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getLoginStatusUrl() in D:\xampp\htdocs\kenshinkan-new\kenshinkan\facebook.php on line 34

<?php
require '/src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$app_id =   'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

    print "<pre>";
  // print_r($result);
    $json_output=($result['summary']['total_count']);
     echo  "$json_output";
    print "</pre>";


} else {
  $statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_friends,read_stream, export_stream'));
}


?>

<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login:<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>                                
    </body>
</html>
```

but this code working yesterday? Today i am getting Error? how to solve this error? i want get friends list from facebook? please any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

I got Answer.  i have just change Line

$statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();

change To

$statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

its Working Good Now...

Comment: Since you are not even _using_ `$statusUrl` anywhere else in your code (at least not in the code you have shown), you might as well remove that line completely. (And even if you where to use it somewhere, it would not make sense, since login URL and login status URL do different things.)